# Efficient replacement of 2d-array elements in R

Tags: arrays, r, replace

I have a quite huge 2d-array with about 3600 x 3600 elements. I want to replace most of the elements by new values, but everything I tried was way too slow. Here is an example:

```
m <- array(NA,c(1000,1000))
x <- sample(1:1000,500000,replace=T)
y <- sample(1:1000,500000,replace=T)
v <- sample(1:10,500000,replace=T)

m[x,y] <- v
```

I found similar questions for dataframes, but I wasn't able to apply this for my case. I would be very grateful if someone could show me a faster solution.

Comment: Assuming that 'x' and 'y' are the row/column indexes, do you need `m[cbind(x,y)] <- v`  and if that is the case, your example runs in my machine `system.time(m[cbind(x,y)] <- v)#
   user  system elapsed #
   0.01    0.00    0.01`

Comment: `everything I tried was way too slow` Show what you have tried. Make sure that your code gives the intended result. Include benchmarks in your question. Define what would be "fast enough".

Comment: @akrun: That's it! It's working perfectly and fast. But, I do not really understand why it is so much faster. Do you have an explanation? I would like to avoid similar mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 'x' and 'y' are row/column indices, the option would be to `cbind` it together to extract the elements of 'm' in that position and assign it to the values in 'v'.  It will be faster.  Based on the example provided,

```
system.time(m[cbind(x,y)] <- v)
# user system elapsed
# 0.01 0.00 0.01
```

---

When we do,

```
m[x, y]
```

it is getting the rows and the columns corresponding to all the x's and 'y's which would be a huge matrix with dimension 500000 X 500000 and it takes a lot of time to load as well and is incorrect as well

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.